# HTTP Request failing - An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

We are using the following code to call a .NET Web API . The service is hosted on IIS with Windows Authentication. The service call is initiated from a console job. (Both service and console are on .NET framework 4.5 both).

The `_payload` which is posted is large (~4990 KB). The service web.config already has `maxRequestLenghth` set to a large value. It does not fail for small requests.

Interestingly it takes 5 minutes every time for the request to fail. The 401 for NTLM Authentication is present in IIS logs, but nothing after that.

I guess this is a timeout issue, please help

Code :

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse> InvokeService()
                {
                string clientBaseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBaseAddress"];
                string requestUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceRequestUri"];
                HttpClient client;
                ServiceResponse serviceResponse = null;
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true
                };
                client = new HttpClient(handler);
                using (client)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(clientBaseAddress);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, _payLoad);

                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                 return serviceResponse;
                }
```

Exception

> service call start  :5:21:16 AM
>
> Exception caught-
>
> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>     at BES_SPServiceTest.Program.d__1.MoveNext()
>
> Inner exception :
>
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> Inner's inner exception
>
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Net.TlsStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> Inner's inner's inner exception
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> stop  :5:26:16 AM

Comment: does the service you are posting to configured to accept large files?

Comment: are you calling a https endpoint?

Comment: Yes I am using HTTPS (Its production)and for large files I have set `maxRequestLength` in web.config to a large value. Is anything else required ?

Comment: I was able to get rid of these issues by using singleton instances of the HTTPClient and using async tasks, these links might help, I know the thread is old but I'm still looking on how to solve some issues with HttpClient [You're using httpClient the wrong way](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) [Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) [ASP Core.NET IHttpClientFactory for Http resilent requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implemen